# Distributing iPhone Apps To Private Clients

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Since I am new to iOS development I have a few Questions. Firstly I did read some of the other related questions I just want to clarify a few things.

As I understand it:

1. I can make an app for a client and then the client can purchase the app for me and register a Enterprise account and then be able to distribute the app in house. But they need to have 500+ employees to be able to subscribe for Enterprise.
2. I can make an app and distribute it to end users in the normal manner. Nothing funky about this.

Now my questions are, what way should one go about when you want to create an in house app for a client with less than 500 employees, which means they can't register for a enterprise account? And is it posible to list an app for free on app store but you can only use it if you have a license code that you need to enter to unlock the app, so basically when Jon Doe downloads the app he can't use it, but if the client downloads the app they enter the code and the app then gets unlocked?

Edit: Not Applicable Anymore, See Edit 2: Ok did some more research, another problem I        will be facing in the new future is that South African companies can't get a DUNS number which is required for the enterprise license, so basically that route is blocked for me, because of that problem. So what other way is there to go about this?

Edit 2: After some further research I found that the DUNS number can be obtained outside the US and that South Africa is listed as a country in which a DUNS number can be obtained. Can anyone out side the US and mostly outside Europe confirm that DUNS numbers are available in their countries, and actually know of companies in there country that has one. And I know I am going of topic but how can I check if a company has a DUNS number.

Thanks

Comment: yes it is possible....you can have passcode for authentication before starting application.

Comment: I doubt apple will approve that in the store.

Comment: I heard that apple usually does not accept such apps. You should rather provide some "available for all" content in such application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, most probably the 500+ employee restriction is not applied any more for enterprise distribution. But, the company which want to apply for enterprise development account need a D.U.N.S registration number.

The other way to distribute the app is to use ad-hoc distribution. You can have at most 100 mobile phones in your company where you install ad-hoc version of the app.

You can make an app with an access code and mark it free in the app store. The app can be used only some people who have the access code. But when Apple people will review it, you need to give an access code to them too, to review and see inside the app. This is absolutely legal. And it works.

Comment: really?  You've done it?  I'm astounded they would approve this.  People could do this and then sell those access codes and cut apple out of their 30%.

Comment: I have read about the add hoc on some of the other questions and it appears to me that the Add Hoc stuff expires after a while, is this true? And that wont work since if a company expands over 100 I will be screwed. I honestly think that the best way will be the access code. But what if the client doesn't want the app to appear in the app store?

Comment: @Dad. I'v done that. But probably apple observe the number of downloads. If its too much/timeframe, they may not approve that anymore.

Comment: @Armand. Ad hoc apps expires with after some time. Usually as soon as your developer account expire. so max timeframe is one year. The other way is to get a DUNS number.

Comment: @karim Check updated question please, and can you confirm what I said in the edit2

Comment: I am not sure of that, since I am not from that region. But I think if the organization have good credit record, they can get it. If you check in their website, http://www.dnb.com/.